# Inverse of Infinite Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, infinite-matrices

Let $B, C$ be two $2\times 2$ matrices with complex entries. Let an infinite block matrix $H$ be given by its component: $H_{n,n'} = B \delta_{n,n'+1}  + B^\dagger \delta_{n,n'-1} + C \delta_{n,n'} $. Here, $(n,n')\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

How can I find the inverse of $H$?

Note: I came to this problem by trying to find the Green's function of a nearest-neighbor Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is translation-invariant, perform a Fourier series to get a matrix-multiplication operator on $L^2(S^1)$ given by the matrix
$$ h(k) = B e^{-ik}+B^\ast e^{ik} + C = 2\Re\{B\} \cos(k) + 2\Im\{B\} \sin(k) + C \quad\forall k\in[0,2\pi]\,. $$

Assuming $C$ is self-adjoint $H$ has real ac-spectrum which may or may not include $0$ depending on the choice of $B$ and $C$. If it doesn't include $0$ then the $2\times2$ matrix $h(k)$ may be inverted at each $k$ and then transformed back to $H$ (the result will probably not be finite-hopping).